# Server for streaming from android to web

Tags: android

I am trying to develop an android application that will stream the video from android mobile to the web (similar to Qik). I had gone through RED5, MAMMOTH and RTMPD servers.

My question is which web server I should use? Which is the best supported on android? Is there any other alternative to do this?

If there is some tutorial or code is available, please point it to me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the testing purpose, I had developed a small application in C# which serves as server. It captures the streamed data and display it in video format.

For the implementation of actual server, I used [gstreamer](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/). Implementation of gstreamer is also available for Android.